# How to abort/stop an Amazon AWS s3 upload in progress

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I am using the javascript version of the aws sdk to upload a file to an amazon s3 bucket.

code :

```
AWS.config.update({
                accessKeyId : 'access-key',
                secretAccessKey : 'secret-key'
            });
            AWS.config.region = 'region';
            var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucket-name'}});
            //var fileChooser = document.getElementById('file');
            var files = event.target.files;
            $.each(files, function(i, file){
            //console.log(file.name);
                if (file) {
                    var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
                    bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
                        console.log("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%');
                        if("Uploaded :: " + parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total)+'%' == 'Uploaded :: 20%'){
                            console.log("abort upload");
                            bucket.abort.bind(bucket);
                        }
                    }).send(function(err, data) {
                        if(err != "null"){
                            console.log(data);
                            //alert("Upload Success \nETag:"+ data.ETag + "\nLocation:"+ data.Location);
                            var filename = data.Location.substr(data.Location.lastIndexOf("/")+1, data.Location.length-1);
                            console.log(filename);
                            fileData = filename;
                            filename = filename.replace("%20"," ");
                            $('.aws-file-content').append('<i id="delete-aws-file'+i+'" class="delete-aws-file icon-remove-sign"  data-filename=' + fileData +'></i><a href="'+data.Location+'" target=_blank >'+filename+'</a><br>');
                        }else{
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

While the file is uploading parts of the file successfully and is still in progress, I want to abort/stop the file upload.

I tried:

```
 bucket.abort();// not working
 bucket.abort.bind(bucket); //not working.
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution :

```
// replaced bucket.upload() with bucket.putObject()
var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
request = bucket.putObject(params);
```

then for abort the request:

```
abort: function(){
            request.abort();
        }
```

Comment: switching to the `putObject` method eliminates the multipart upload magic that `s3.upload` does under the hood. Any uploads that fail will need to restart from the beginning using `putObject`, with `s3.upload` it uses `AWS.S3.MangaedUpload` under the hood and automagically chunks your file and sends it in parts allowing for a mid-file retry.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot bind from the `bucket` which is your S3 object, it must be called for the upload part.

change for something like this

```
var upload = bucket.upload(params)
upload.send(....)
```

so you can bind on upload like

```
upload.abort.bind(upload);
```

you can call within an timeout method as crowned in the [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html)

```
// abort request in 1 second
setTimeout(upload.abort.bind(upload), 1000);
```

Comment: you can call abort from onClick function of button, its fine; the point is that you cannot call abort from your bucket variable as its instance of S3 class and this is not defined. so you need to have an object from bucket.upload(...) on which you can apply the abort method

Answer (score 2):

Calling abort() in the browser environment will not abort any requests that are already in flight. If a multipart upload was created, any parts not yet uploaded will not be sent, and the multipart upload will be cleaned up.

Default value for part size is (5 * 1024 * 1024)

Answer (score 2):

Through dumb luck I've stumbled upon a way to do this for multipart uploads.

The accepted answer forces you to use the `putObject` method, which does not chunk uploads and sends them using the multipart upload API.

The following solution uses the `s3.upload` method of the AWS S3 SDK for Javascript in the Browser. And it seems to work just fine, even though the example from the official documentation doesn't work.

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucket-name'}});
var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
var bucket.upload(params).send();

setTimeout(bucket.abort, 1000);
```

That's it. I just tried calling `bucket.abort()` and it just worked. Not sure why AWS hasn't documented this.