# what the best way to upload larger files to s3 with nodejs aws-sdk? MultipartUpload vs ManagedUpload vs getSignedURL, etc

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, pre-signed-url

Im trying to look over the ways AWS has to offer in order to upload files to s3. When I looked into [their docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) it confused the hell of out me. Looking up to the various resources I came to know a bit more resources like [s3.upload vs s3.putObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442512/difference-between-upload-and-putobject-for-uploading-a-file-to-s3) and others realised there are physical limitations in API gateway and using lambda function to upload a file.

Particularly in case of uploading large file like 1-100 GB AWS suggests multiple methods to upload file to s3. Amongst them are [createMultipartUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property), [ManagedUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html), [getSignedURL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) and tons of other.

**So my Question is:**
What is the best and the easiest way to upload large files to s3 where I also can cancel the upload process. The multipart upload [seems to tedious](https://www.altostra.com/blog/multipart-uploads-with-s3-presigned-url).

Comment: ManagedUpload does the multipart upload but hides the details from you, go with that one. (my opinion)

Comment: can I upload a large file eg 10GB via a single presigned url without multipart? with multipart it seems I need to break file input blob into numerous chunks in frontend which is a tedious and unpleasing process then map them with each individual `uploadID` with fetch or axios

Comment: @RahulAhire Can I ask what technique you've used in the end? Thanks

Comment: I have got my answer, you can [see this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VHc41idHZs) But essentially presigned and multipart upload are totally different things. I've uploaded my answer to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There's no Best Way to upload file to S3**

It depends on what you want especially what are the sizes of the object that you want to upload.

1. [putObject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VHc41idHZs) - Ideal for objects which are under 20MB
2. [Presigned Url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) - Allows you to bypass API Gateway and Put object under 5GB to s3 bucket
3. [Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html) - Allows you to upload files in chunks which means you can continue your upload even the connection went off temporarily. The maximum file size you can upload via this method is 5TB.

Answer (score 2):

Use Streams to upload to S3, this way the Node.JS server doesn't take too much of the resources.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
const stream = require('stream');
 
function upload(S3) {
  let pass = new stream.PassThrough();
 
  let params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET,
    Key: KEY,
    Body: pass
  };
 
  S3.upload(params, function (error, data) {
    console.error(error);
    console.info(data);
  });
 
  return pass;
}
 
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/your/file');
readStream.pipe(upload(S3));
```

**This is via streaming local file, the stream can be from request as well.**

If want to listen to the progress can use ManagedUpload

```
const manager = S3.upload(params);
 
manager.on('httpUploadProgress', (progress) => {
  console.log('progress', progress)
  // { loaded: 6472, total: 345486, part: 3, key: 'large-file.dat' }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit for sharing your answer but I guess there's a problem here. I works fine for local directory but not well suitable for using in lambda function as there's 10MB api gateway limit. So, any suggestion uploading files via single presigned url vs multipartUpload?

Comment: Ok so there is two approach:

1) Upload file to node server and then using stream upload it to s3.
2) Frontend creates a call to the node api and it return a signed url with some config. And frontend can directly upload it to the s3 using respective signed url.

Comment: Your requirement is specifically AWS Lambda?

Comment: I'm actually uploading data from frontend via `formdata()` and it encodes the data in `base64` string. I have seen how to convert it into buffer and just use `s3.putObject` or `s3.upload` but it cause stress to function memory in case of larger file. So there's another way like multipart and presigned URL so my question is can I upload larger files with single presigned URL without any limit or what's the difference between two of those?

Comment: Another solution is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TPIddmgjv4