# upload large chunks of data to s3 using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am writing a small reactjs-server to upload file-chunks to s3.

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import aws4 from 'aws4';

import express from 'express';


let accessKeyId: string, secretAccessKey: string, sessionToken: string;

const sts = new aws.STS();
export const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

app.put('/:bucket_path*', express.raw({ type: '*/*' }),(req, res) => {
  const roleToAssume = {
    RoleArn: process.env.BUCKET_ACCESS_ARN,
    RoleSessionName: generateRandomCharacters(),
    DurationSeconds: Number(process.env.SESSIONDURATION),
  };
  sts.assumeRole(roleToAssume, function (err, data) {
    if (err) logger.error(err.stack);
    else {
      const accessparams = {
        accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
      };
      const s3 = new aws.S3(accessparams);
      req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        const params = {
          Bucket: req.params.bucket_path,
          Key: req.params['0'],
          Body: chunk,
        };
        s3.putObject(params).promise().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
        req.on('end', () => {
          logger.info('Uploaded the object successfully');
          res.end();
        });
      });
      logger.info('assumed desired role to communicate with AWS');
    }
  });
});
```

This works for files with small chunks. However, it fails for larger chunks(uploads only the latest/last chunk) How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use multipart upload for this. Fortunately, this is supported by `@aws-sdk/client-s3` by default.

You can read up on the topic here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html

```
import { PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { s3Client } from "./libs/s3Client.js"; // Helper function that creates Amazon S3 service client module.
import {path} from "path";
import {fs} from "fs";

const file = "OBJECT_PATH_AND_NAME"; // Path to and name of object. For example '../myFiles/index.js'.


// Upload file to specified bucket.
export const run = () => {
  try {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);

    fileStream.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    })

    fileStream.on('data', async (chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk);
        
        // Set the parameters
        const uploadParams = {
          Bucket: "BUCKET_NAME",
          Key: path.basename(file),
          Body: chunk,
        };

        await s3Client.send(
            new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams)
        );
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
run();
```

If you want to use an older sdk you have to use `upload` instead of `putObject`. `putObject` only supports smaller sizes.
[Difference between upload() and putObject() for uploading a file to S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442512/difference-between-upload-and-putobject-for-uploading-a-file-to-s3/38442712#38442712)

If you want to use an even older sdk you can use this function:
`s3.createMultipartUpload(params, function(err, data) {...})`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property

Comment: Hi @Gabor I am actually getting stream/chunks of data there fore i changed the code to as follows based on the documentation
https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ujerumozug.js and the error looks as follows https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/fituwuqohi.apache 
any idea why ?

Comment: you can use Cognito identity pool to authenticate.
Here is an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-browser-credentials-cognito.html