# s3.putObject() uploading file to S3 but then never returning a response?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

export async function putObjectToS3(
  data: any,
  nameOfFile: string,
  contentType: string
) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET || '',
    ContentType: contentType,
    Key: `${nameOfFile}`,
    Body: data
  };

  console.log('start s3 put object');
  const response = await s3.putObject(params).promise();

  console.log('end s3 put object: ', response);
  return response;
}


await putObjectToS3(artistsCsv, `artists/artists.csv`, 'text/csv');
```

We have the following function that uploads a file to AWS S3. This is run in an AWS lambda function. While our `artistsCsv` file is successfully uploaded (we see the CSV file in S3), the function never returns... We see the log `'start s3 put object'` in our logging, but we never see `'end s3 put object: ', response`.

Is there something wrong with the way we have built this function, that is causing it to never return the `response`? We are using `aws-sdk` version `"aws-sdk": "^2.1147.0",`.

Could this simply be an issue with AWS? (seems unlikely though). Perhaps something with the `.promise()`, and `async/await`, that we are missing? How can we even troubleshoot this?

Comment: If you log the `'end s3 put object'` inside a `promise.then`, does it appear? The way you built the function looks ok to me, same as how they do it in their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).

Comment: is it necessary to use aws sdk v2? how about if you use sdkv3

Comment: JS v2 will enter "maintenance mode" in 2023, it's maybe a bug indeed. Have you tried v3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use upload method if putObject doesn't work, it supports promise since 2.6.12(https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2612), so something like this should work:

```js
const response = await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
console.log('end s3 put object: ', response);
```

You can also find a complete example from the original documentation here(it's with callback,but the concept is the same):
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascript/example_code/s3/s3_upload.js

Comment: Do you know if `upload` is supposed to be replacing `putObject` as a more generic function for this? Also, do I need to add any other parameters here or is it the exact same?

Comment: It's pretty much the same, the params are identical, if you want more detailed information take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442512/difference-between-upload-and-putobject-for-uploading-a-file-to-s3

Comment: @alexHX12 support for `promise` was first introduced in version [`v2.3.0`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/)

Comment: @alexHX12 the function hangs with `s3.upload` as well, unfortunately. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Maybe the problem is external of lambda itself, try to check logs and VPC configuration