# In Go package AWS S3 : what's the difference between Upload() and PutObject()?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, go-modules

When I was researching about how to upload to S3 in Go, I saw that some articles used Upload() (via uploader instance) and some use PutObject() to upload file.

I read the AWS S3 package docs, but I am still confused.

So what's the difference between this two, or when should I use which one ?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442512/difference-between-upload-and-putobject-for-uploading-a-file-to-s3